# JOOQ: multisetAgg or toSet filtering out NULL

Tags: jooq

Quite often, the new feature of multisetAgg is used along with LEFT JOINs.

Let's say, I have a user as dimension table and fact table paid_subscriptions. I want to query a specific user with all of his paid subscriptions and for each subscription do some processing (like sending an email or whatever).

I would write some JOOQ like this:

```
ctx
                .select(row(
                        USER.ID,
                        USER.USERNAME,
                        multisetAgg(PAIDSUBSCRIPTIONS.SUBNAME).as("subscr").convertFrom(r -> r.intoSet(Record1::value1))
                        ).mapping(MyUserWithSubscriptionPOJO::new)
                )
                .from(USER)
                .leftJoin(PAIDSUBSCRIPTIONS).onKey()
                .where(someCondition)
                .groupBy(USER)
                .fetch(Record1::value1));
```

The problem here is: the multisetAgg produces a Set which can contain null as element.

I either heve to filter out the null subscriptions I don't care about after JOOQ select, or I have to rewrite my query with something like this:

```
multisetAgg(PAIDSUBSCRIPTIONS.SUBNAME).as("subscr").convertFrom(r -> {
                                    final Set<String> res = r.intoSet(Record1::value1);
                                    res.remove(null); // remove possible nulls
                                    return res;
                                })
```

Both don't look too nice in code.

I wonder if there is a better approach to write this with less code or even an automatic filtering of null values or some other kind of syntactic sugar avilable in JOOQ? After all, I think it is quite a common usecase especially considering that often enough, I end up with some java8 style stream processing of my left joined collection and first step is to filter out null which is something I forget often :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a few things here:

- `SET` instead of `MULTISET` (will be addressed with [#12033](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12033))
- Adding `NULL` filtering (is already possible with `FILTER`)
- The implied idea that such `NULL` values could be removed automatically (might be addressed with [#13776](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13776))

### `SET` instead of `MULTISET`

The SQL standard has some notions of a `SET` as opposed to `MULTISET` or `ARRAY`. For example:

- [#13795](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13795)

It isn't as powerful as `MULTISET`, and it doesn't have to be, because usually, just by adding `DISTINCT` you can turn any `MULTISET` into a `SET`. Nevertheless, Informix (possibly the most powerful ORDBMS) does have `SET` data types and constructors:

- [`LIST` (`ARRAY`)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-liste-data-type)
- [`MULTISET`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-multisete-data-type)
- [`SET`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-sete-data-type)

So, we might add support for this in the future, perhaps. I'm not sure yet of its utility, as opposed to using `DISTINCT` with `MULTISET` (already possible) or `MULTISET_AGG` (possible soon):

- [#12033](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12033)

### Adding `NULL` filtering

[You already have the `FILTER` clause to do this directly in SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/aggregate-filter/). It's a SQL standard and supported by jOOQ natively, or via `CASE` emulations. A native SQL example, as supported by e.g. PostgreSQL:

```sql
select 
  t.a, 
  json_agg(u.c),
  json_agg(u.c) filter (where u.b is not null)
from (values (1), (2)) t (a)
left join (values (2, 'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c'),(3, 'd')) u (b, c) on t.a = u.b
group by t.a
```

Producing:

```
|a  |json_agg  |json_agg  |
|---|----------|----------|
|1  |[null]    |          |
|2  |["a", "b"]|["a", "b"]|
```

So, just write:

```java
multisetAgg(PAIDSUBSCRIPTIONS.SUBNAME).filter(PAIDSUBSCRIPTIONS.ID.isNotNull())
```

### The implied idea that such `NULL` values could be removed automatically

Note, I understand that you'd probably like this to be done automatically. There's a thorough discussion on that subject here: [#13776](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13776). As always, it's a desirable thing that is far from easy to implement consistently.

I'm positive that this will be done eventually, but it's a very big change.